# How to create real number matrix from a complex number

Tags: python

A 1D complex number can be converted to a 2D real number matrix as shown below. How can I implement it in python?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose, you have a complex number `z`:

```
np.array([[z.real, z.imag], [-z.imag, z.real]])
```